# How to export from a php array to a CSV file and also import CSV back into the php file

Tags: php, arrays, csv, import, export

I have a php script that is for advertising domains for sale. The list of domains and their values are in the config.php file as an array. It is very time consuming to edit the config file manually to modify and add over 100 domains, so i would like to bulk edit if possible. So is there a way i can export/download the domain array list as a CSV file (so I can add/edit domains with a spreadsheet program) and then import the modified CSV file back into the config.php (overwrite the old array data with updated domain info). So if you see the code there are values for 'domainurl', 'nicename', 'price', 'lease_price', 'enable_purchase_type_field', 'description', 'not_for_sale', and 'image'.

Any ideas? Thank you for your advice!

```
$domains = array(
  'mydomain.com' => [
        'nicename' => 'domainone.com',
        'price' => '$1000',
        'lease_price' => '$100',
        'enable_purchase_type_field' => true,
        'description' => 'description of domain one for sale',
        'not_for_sale' => false,
        'image' => 'tech.png'
    ], 
    'domaintwo.tld' => [
        'nicename' => 'domaintwo.com',
        'price' => '$2000',
        'lease_price' => '$200',
        'enable_purchase_type_field' => true,
        'description' => 'description of domain two for sale',
        'not_for_sale' => false,
        'image' => 'money.png'
    ], 
    'domainthree.tld' => [
        'nicename' => 'domainthree.com',
        'price' => '$3000',
        'lease_price' => '$300',
        'enable_purchase_type_field' => true,
        'description' => 'description of domain three for sale',
        'not_for_sale' => false,
        'image' => 'nature.png'
    ],
```

I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to save the domain data to the file domain_details.csv:

```
$data = array(array('nicename', 'price', 'lease_price', 'enable_purchase_type_field', 'description', 'not_for_sale', 'image'));
foreach ($domains as $domain_name => $domain_data) {
    $data[] = array(array_values($domain_data));    
}

$fp = fopen('domain_details.csv', 'w');
for ($count = 0; $count < count($data); $count++) {
    fputcsv($fp, $data[$count]);
}
fclose($fp);
```

The code uses the [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

Answer (score 0):

**Page 1**
----------------------------------------html----------------------------------------

```
<div class="box-body">                  
                                <center>Import <b>Data</b> from CSV file</center><br><br>                               
                                <div id="regImageDiv" class="form-group">
                                    <label for="regStaffImage" class="col-sm-5" style="text-align:right">DATA</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7" style="text-align:left">
                                        <?php /*"<form class="form-horizontal" action="hex-upload-process.php" method="post" name="upload_csv" id="upload_csv" enctype="multipart/form-data">"*/ ?>
                                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="hex-upload-process-mp.php" method="post" name="upload_csv" id="upload_csv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="perId" name="perId" value="<?php echo $selectedMonth ?>">
                                            <p class="help-block">Choose <i>.csv </i> file only.</p>
                                            <span id="imageSpan" class="help-block" style="display:none"></span>
                                    </div><br><br><br><br>              
                                    <center>
                                        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="Import" class="btn btn-info pull-center" data-loading-text="Loading..." onClick="loading()"><b>IMPORT</b>
                                        </button>
                                    </center>
                                    </br>
                                    <center>
                                        <a href="hex-upload.php?clear=true"><b>CLEAR ALL SCHEDULING DATA</b></a>
                                    </center>
                                        </br>
                                    <center>
                                        <span id="hex-upload-span" name="hex-upload-span"  class="help-block" style="visibility:hidden"/>
                                    </center>
                                        </form> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

-------------------------------------------js------------------------------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function loading(){
         //$('#loader').show();
        $('#loader').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#upload_csv').submit();
    }
<script>
```

**PAGE 2**
process.php

```
    <?php //Latest build 18/06/2019 11:00AM

    ini_set('max_execution_time' , 1200); ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); include ("include/connect.php"); session_start(); $currentDate = date('Y-m-d'); $type = "daily";

    //check file if uploaded 
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){
        $filenamehistory=$_FILES["file"]["name"];   
        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

        //fetch all data in imported csv file by user   
$file = fopen($filename, "r");  $x = 1;     $csv = "";  while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){      ${"JobNo_".$x} = $getData[0];       ${"Model_".$x} = $getData[1];       ${"ProdQty_".$x} = $getData[2];         ${"SDate_".$x} = $getData[3];       ${"EDate_".$x} = $getData[4];       ${"Status_".$x} = $getData[5];      ${"CurSDate_".$x} = $getData[6];        ${"CurPQty_".$x} = $getData[7];         ${"LineNo_".$x} = $getData[8];      ${"Remark_".$x} = $getData[9];      ${"IsdOnly_".$x} = $getData[10];        ${"Cond_".$x} = $getData[11];       ${"Evap_".$x} = $getData[12];
                    if($getData[3] != 0){                   $dataStartDt = date_create_from_format('j/m/Y', $getData[3]);           ${"SDate_".$x} = date_format($dataStartDt, 'Y-m-d');        }else{          ${"SDate_".$x} = "0000-00-00";      }       $getData[3] = ${"SDate_".$x};
                    if($getData[4] != 0){           $dataEndDt = date_create_from_format('j/m/Y', $getData[4]);             ${"EDate_".$x} = date_format($dataEndDt, 'Y-m-d');      }else{          ${"EDate_".$x} = "0000-00-00";      }
                    if($getData[6] != 0){           $dataCurrStartDt = date_create_from_format('j/m/Y', $getData[6]);           ${"CurSDate_".$x} = date_format($dataCurrStartDt, 'Y-m-d');         }else{          ${"CurSDate_".$x}
    = "0000-00-00";         }
                    ${$getData[3].$getData[0].$getData[6]} = $x;
                    $csv .= ${"JobNo_".$x}.','.${"Model_".$x}.','.${"ProdQty_".$x}.','.${"SDate_".$x}.','.${"EDate_".$x}.','.${"Status_".$x}.','.${"CurSDate_".$x}.','.${"CurPQty_".$x}.','.${"LineNo_".$x}.','.${"Remark_".$x}.','.${"IsdOnly_".$x}.','.${"Cond_".$x}.','.${"Evap_".$x}."\n";
                    $x++;   }   $totaldata = $x;    fclose($file);

            $csv_filename = "csvfile/".$filenamehistory;    $csv_handler = fopen ($csv_filename,'w');   fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);     fclose ($csv_handler); } else{  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");window.location = \"hex-upload.php\"</script>";  die(); }
```

please copy to notepad++ first. This code use fopen, fclose, fwrite, fgetcsv

see at my $csv to understand how its data looks like. This use "," to separate column "\n" to separate row.

**OR you can use phpexcel instead**